# How correctly parse string value in JAVA from text in sum?

Tags: java, sum, numbers

i have a problem with one task in Java. I have text file with these numbers -

input : 000000004599
000000001000

And the result should be -
output: 45.99
10.00
sum of two varriables - 5599  (yes,without "dot")

I only have guesses that it is necessary to remove numbers from the beginning through the array.
Example :
if (arr[i] = 0 && arr[i + 1] = 0) {
...
}

I'm sure there is another logical solution

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("000000004599") + Integer.parseInt("000000001000")` gives the result you want.

Comment: Happy to help. I've now posted that as an answer.

Comment: I Will confirm it after 7 min.

Comment: @Destroyer369, if there are leading or trailing white-space characters, it will not parse.  Zeros are fine.

Comment: @Reilas There's no indication of that being a possible input. But using `String#trim` before parsing is simple.

Comment: @Unmitigated, I meant it as reference, not as an implication.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply use `Integer.parseInt`.

```java
Integer.parseInt("000000004599") + Integer.parseInt("000000001000"); // 5599
```

Answer (score 1):

So `String.replaceFirst()` replaces the matched regex (in this case `^0+(?!$)`) The regex ^0+(?!$) matches sequences of one or more consecutive zeros at the beginning of a line or string, excluding any trailing zeros.

Then using `Double.parseDouble()` we can get the double value of the strings.

Then `String.format()` allows you to format strings depending on a specified locale. In this case `"%.2f"` means that the number should be formatted as a floating-point number (f) with two decimal places (.2). The reason the number are divided by 100 is to get the last two digits into the decimal places (eg. 4599 -> 45.99).

`sumString` simply is the answer to the first part of your question--the 2 numbers added together replacing the dot from the double with an empty string.

The rest is just putting them both together into your specified format.

```java
    public static String convertAndSum(String input1, String input2) {
        // Remove leading zeros from the inputs
        String number1 = input1.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
        String number2 = input2.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
        
        // Convert the inputs to double values
        double value1 = Double.parseDouble(number1);
        double value2 = Double.parseDouble(number2);
        
        // Format the values to two decimal places
        String formattedValue1 = String.format("%.2f", value1 / 100);
        String formattedValue2 = String.format("%.2f", value2 / 100);
        
        // Calculate the sum of the values
        int sum = (int) (value1 + value2);
        
        // Format the sum as a string without the dot
        String sumString = String.valueOf(sum).replace(".", "");
        
        // Create the output string
        String output = "output: " + formattedValue1 + " " + formattedValue2 +
                        " sum of two variables - " + sumString;
        
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: You could skip the _regex_ and use _while (number.charAt(index++) == '0');_ to get an index.  Nice code, though.